# IAM Eclipse plugin - error repository

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin

I've tried to install the IAM Eclipse plugin, but I get the following error:

**No repository found at http://q4e.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite-iam/.**

How could I solve it? I've searched in Google, but I don't find any useful thing for my problem.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases may resolve your issue. Guess you are going to do Maven Integration for Eclipse.
http://q4e.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite-iam/ --> Throws 404 error.
If your requirement is maven integration, you can use the given url
```

Comment: I use: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases , 
it worked fine for me, but I was worried about using: http://q4e.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite-iam/ --> could I use one of them? I thought that I had to use both of urls. Thanks so much!